# Starting fragment on button click in DialogPreference

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, dialog-preference

I have a PreferenceActivity from which I am trying to create a dialogpreference on click of preference. I first tried to keep my DialogPreference class (MyPreferencefragment) outside the PreferenceActivity class and the layout was

```
  <com.example.second.MyPreferencefragment
    android:dialogMessage="Demo"
    android:key="resetDialog"
    android:negativeButtonText="No"
    android:persistent="false"
    android:positiveButtonText="Yes"
    android:summary="Place the time here"
    android:title="Demo App"  />
```

This was fine but my dialogpreference has a button, on click of which I need to open a fragment. How can this be achieved? I do not have FragmentManager in Dialogpreference.

I tried creating DialogPreference as inner class in my PreferenceActivity but the layout of dialog preference came out to be as following.

```
 <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


     <DialogPreference class = "com.example.second.PrefsActivity$MyPreferencefragment"
    android:dialogMessage="Demo"
    android:key="resetDialog"
    android:negativeButtonText="No"
    android:persistent="false"
    android:positiveButtonText="Yes"
    android:summary="Place the time here"
    android:title="Demo App"  />
```

This throws an exception

```
    Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class android.preference.DialogPreference
  01-15 05:54:01.427: E/AndroidRuntime(12843):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
```

This is useless as DialogPreference is an abstract class.

I just have to start a fragment on click of button from dialogpreference. How can this be achieved? Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Edit:: Adding the whole stack

```
01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.second/com.example.second.PrefsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2253)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1438)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
  01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5236)
  01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1257)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1073)
01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:397)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:272)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:1778)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at com.example.tapholdcustom.PrefsActivity.onCreate(PrefsActivity.java:38)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2217)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    ... 11 more
  01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class android.preference.DialogPreference
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:383)
01-15 05:27:41.325: E/AndroidRuntime(8932):     ... 22 more
```

My major concerns are:

1. Open custom dialogpreference on click of preference
2. Open a fragment on click of a button in custom dialogpreference (There are three buttons in custom dialogpreference)

I can achieve 1 by not using dialogpreference as an inner class as it is giving me the abovementioned stacktrace. But how do I achieve second point?

Comment: So your problem is Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5, please include the XML you are inflating now

Comment: The second xml mentioned above is the xml which is throwing the exception.

Comment: Yes, but the fragment itself must also have some XML it's inflating

Comment: I used dialogfragment instead of dialogpreference and the problem was solved. Thank you for your help guys, really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a container (typically a frame layout), then you swap the fragment into that container with a fragment transaction. That exception alone isn't very descriptive, I'm not sure what you did before you got it - you need at least the two-param constructor present to use fragment via XML, otherwise make sure you have an empty constructor if you've tried to call it that way (in code).

Post the rest of your stack trace, there should be a caused-by.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.your_container_id, new YourFragment()).commit();
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have the required constructors for the dialogpreference as it is working fine when i take it out of the preferenceActivity class. The dialogpreference opens fine then. But then I need to open a fragment which I am not being able to do so as I do not have control over fragmentManager anymore. For this, I tried moving the code in the preferenceActivity so that I could try something but then the dialogpreference is not opening as it throws the exception as i have mentioned in the question.